# Given a ticker symbol, how can I know the corresponding SEC Edgar's Central Index Key (CIK)?

Tags: stocks, sec, edgar, ticker-symbols

I read on https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/cik.htm:

> The Central Index Key (CIK) is used on the SEC's computer systems to identify corporations.

Given a ticker symbol, how can I know the corresponding Edgar's CIK?

---

For example, for the ticker symbol [AXAHY](https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/AXAHY), searching for `AXAHY` on https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/companysearch.html returns nothing, and searching for `AXA` returns many results. I'm not looking for the CIK of `AXAHY` in particular (which I think is `0000898427`), but a principled way to know the Edgar's CIK given a ticker symbol.

Searching for `AXA` returns many results on https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/companysearch.html:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this directly from the SEC.

- In text format: https://www.sec.gov/include/ticker.txt

  The first column is the ticker, and the second column is the CIK for that ticker.
  Sample:

  ```
  a 1090872
  aa    1675149
  aaap  1611787
  aacg  1420529
  aach  1606180
  aacqu 1802457
  aagh  1098009
  ...
  ```
- In JSON format: https://www.sec.gov/files/company_tickers.json

  Sample:

  ```
  {
      "0":{"cik_str":1750,"ticker":"AIR","title":"AAR CORP"},
      "1":{"cik_str":1800,"ticker":"ABT","title":"ABBOTT LABORATORIES"},
      "2":{"cik_str":1961,"ticker":"WDDD","title":"WORLDS INC"},
      "3":{"cik_str":2034,"ticker":"ACET","title":"ACETO CORP"},
      ...
  }
  ```

More information about getting EDGAR data: https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/accessing-edgar-data.htm

Related question on Quantitative Finance StackExchange: [Central Index Key (CIK) of all traded stocks](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/8099)

Answer (score 1):

[mainst](https://www.reddit.com/user/mainst) [pointed](https://www.reddit.com/r/investing/comments/i0xg2k/given_a_ticker_symbol_how_can_i_know_the/fztbhp8/) me to https://sec.report/CIK/, which indeed does the job.

[image]

->

[image]